# Moment of Inertia (Square Laminas)

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

If I have a uniform square lamina of side length 2a and intend to find its Moment Of Inertia about a perpendicular axis to its plane, is there a general formula for this? If there isn't, I have tried splitting the shape into two rectangles of sides 2a and a; finding the MOI for each rectangle is easy, but adding these MOIs up doesn't seem right.

please note, the perpendicular axis is through the centre of the shape

Please, any suggestions (along the line of topic) will help; I just need another way of thinking about this. Thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific about where the perpendicular axis is

Comment: Centre of the shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using standard results, and not direct integration, to obtain the MI about the $z$ axis perpendicular to the plane through the centre, then firstly, the MI of the square lamina of mass $m$ and sides $2a$ about a diameter of the square (the $x$ and $y$ axes) is $$\frac 13ma^2$$
Then apply the Perpendicular Axes Theorem so that $$I_z=I_x+I_y$$ so the answer is $$\frac 23ma^2$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint we can have another axis in the same plane . so let the given axis in plane be $I_x$ and we draw a new axis which is in the same plane of the lamina lets say $I_y$ thus the axis perpendicular to the lamina be $I_z$ thus by perpendicular axis theorem we have $2I_z=I_x+I_y$ now we know moment of inertia about $X-axis,Y-axis $  which is $\frac{1}{3}ML^2$ now can you get $I_z$

Comment: you mean (1/3)ML^2 ?

Comment: Yes my mistake let me edit

Answer (score 1):

If the axis passes through the center of the lamina, then you just need to evaluate
$$
\int_{-a}^a\int_{-a}^a(x^2+y^2)\rho\ dxdy,
$$
which is quite easy (density $\rho$ is constant).

Comment: Well, integrating between those limits may be much easier; but this question actually comes along before the section on integration (in the book I'm studying with); so I intend to work out the method(s) other than integration, that can solve this problem. So, apart from integrating, do you know of any other way of doing this?

Comment: It all depends on which methods are you then allowed to use.

Comment: I'm presuming there must be a way of finding it out asides integration. This question comes along before the book talks of integration. So, this is simply the part where you use already proven formulae like that of the rectangular lamina - (Md^2)/3 - e.t.c.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know your book, but if you already have the solution for a rectangular lamina, why not using that in the case of a square? I mean: a square IS a (particular case of) rectangle.

Comment: Funny you should say that because I have tried that and it gives the right answer; I just don't have enough conviction that this is the right thing to do. The lengths of the sides are not the same, so I was thinking that would be an incorrect thing to do. If this is right though, do you suggest that I may use the formula for the rectangle for all quadrilaterals?

Comment: No: that works for a rectangle, i.e. a quadrilateral with four right angles. But it doesn't matter if its sides are of different lengths or not.